# Ruby version conflicts in "rails c / s" commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I have installed all the gems in my existing ruby on rails project. But when the time I tried to run the application it always complaining the following.

```
efuturess-mbp:Actionrev-average-costing efutures$ rails c
Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.5
efuturess-mbp:Actionrev-average-costing efutures$ rbenv install 2.3.5
rbenv: /Users/efutures/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N)
```

This is my GEM file.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.3.5"

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem "RedCloth", "~> 4.2.9"
gem "active_shipping", "~> 1.7"
gem "activerecord-import"
gem "apartment"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "email_validator"
gem "flutie"
gem "googlecharts", "~> 1.6.8"
gem "mini_magick", "~> 3.8.1"
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.21"
gem "neat", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "net-ssh"
gem "normalize-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "omniauth-stripe-connect", "~> 2.9"
gem "pikaday-gem"
gem "pothoven-attachment_fu"
gem "prawn"
gem "prawn-table"
gem "puma_worker_killer"
gem "rack-cors", require: "rack/cors"
gem "rack-mini-profiler", "~> 0.10.1"
gem "rack-rewrite", "~> 1.5"
gem "rails", "~> 5.1.5"
gem "recipient_interceptor"
gem "rollbar", "~> 2.12"
gem "simple_form", "~> 3.2"
gem "stripe", "~> 1.41"
gem "sucker_punch"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.7"
gem "xmlrpc"
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.2"
gem "fog", require: "fog/aws/storage"
gem "fog-aws", "<= 0.1.1", require: false
gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.5"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem "memory_profiler"
gem "puma", "~> 3.7"
gem "rails-jquery-autocomplete"
gem "record_tag_helper", "~> 1.0"
gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.0"
gem "therubyracer", platforms: :ruby
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"

gem "bootstrap-datepicker-rails"
gem "american_date"
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening like this. If someone can help me to sort out this that would be really helpful.

Comment: What output if  type`rbenv version`, `ruby -v` and `which ruby`?

Comment: Hi,
rbenv version => 2.3.5 (set by /Users/efutures/.rbenv/version), ruby -v => ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-darwin18], which ruby => /Users/efutures/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version try creating a `.ruby-version` file on your project's folder so rbenv sets the specified version.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear in the error message. Your problem is that your current ruby version is `2.3.7` and your project uses version `2.3.5`, that causes the conflict. You can try adding a file named `.ruby-version` in your project directory so that `rbenv` know and auto switch between versions, or suggest you to install one if not that version not yet installed.

```
# In file .ruby-version
2.3.5
```

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version).

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about your answer. I created the .ruby-version and added above content. Then again tried the "rails s" command. But still getting the previous error message. Can u please let me know how to proceed. I am bit new to Ruby language as well.

Comment: After adding that file, please leave that directory by `cd ..` and go back, and let me know what you see.

Comment: Yes as u said I created the .ruby-version file and added the version as 2.3.5. That's it. And by sitting inside that project root in the terminal I tried the "rails s" command. I even restarted the terminal as well.

Comment: Please leave the project root directory and go back, rbenv should tell you to install version 2.3.5 if not yet installed, else it will just switch the version to what in the .ruby-version file.

Comment: FYI i just run tboth rbenv global and rbenv local. I was getting 2.3.5

Comment: That's also work, but you will have to run the same commands when you change ruby version.

Comment: Yes as you said I am one step back from the project root. I done "cd.." After I tried this "rbenv install 2.3.5" I was getting the following.
efutures$ rbenv install 2.3.5
rbenv: /Users/efutures/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N)

Comment: So it means in my system I have ruby version 2.3.5 but the system cannot understand that it exists ?

Comment: When you reentering the project directory the ruby version already switch, because you already have that version installed, that's why you get that error when you try to install it again. Next step is to `bundle` the project and `rails s` or `rails c` as you need.

Comment: Oh God..... Still that error is there even after doing a bundle.... :(

Comment: Still it is this...
"Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.5"
I even restarted my mac book :(

Comment: Are you sure you have the file named `.ruby-version` that begins with dot?

Comment: Yes I again checked the file name and the content. the file name is ".ruby-version" and it content was "2.3.5"

Comment: I think stackoverflow has chat feature where we can discuss long conversion, but I don't find it from here, can you check? Chatting might get thing solved faster.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Coco. I cannot add myself to the chat since I dont have much reputation in stack overflow. That could be the reason. If you dont mind can we "Skype" the matter ? I am really confused and done everything I can by checking lot of articles. But nothing helped me.

Comment: Hi @Coco I added

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
echo '2.3.5' > .ruby-version
rbenv rehash
rbenv local 2.3.5
rbenv global 2.3.5
bundle exec rails c
```